# VS2017 - Can't Publish Project (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a WebAPI project that I can't publish. When I right click on the project name and hit "Publish", I'm getting:

[image]

`tmp17CF.tmp` says:

```
11/07/2019 11:01:44
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.InitializeProvider(IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.CreateViewAsync(IVsHierarchy project, IAsyncServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.ManagedPublishProvider.<CreateViewAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
===================
```

I found some ideas of how to fix it on the web, none of them worked:

1. Updating VS2017 code
2. Deleting .bin folder
3. Deleting .obj folder

None of them worked

Thanks!